# Using Selenium in Android

Tags: android, selenium

I have just started using selenium to do some HTML parsing in a java project, but for some reason, when I try to run it in an Android environment, I get a ClassDefNotFound error.

I set up my classpath the same way for both java/android projects and have the correct standalone jar.
Is there any reason why Android cannot accomplish this even with the supplied library?

Also I am using Eclipse, developing on Android API 16.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the .jar to `yourproject/libs/`. ADT scans this folder ('libs', not 'lib') for libraries, and sometimes gets confused if they're added manually from somewhere else.

Don't forget to refresh the folder in the package browser after you add it.